# How to check if SQLite database exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

How can I check if a database exists? I have a database named username that is supposed to be created if it doesn't exist but how can I check if it exists at all?

Comment: SQLite databases are files. You should know the path where the DB will be created so you can check if that file exists.

Comment: Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You should just use [`fileExistsAtPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CHDDDDJG). For example, to do special handling if the database doesn't exist:

```
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathForDb])
{
    // file doesn't exist, so do whatever copying from bundle or 
    // programmatic creation/configuration of the database here.
}
```